# Django URL : Redirect to a url having input from a form

Tags: django

I want the user after its registration, to redirect to a page with URL containing his/her name. I tried passing it as input in urls.py and passing name an variable in the view but its showing name variable insted of the person's name. Please help

Comment: Please show urls and views with code you already tried to go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django's authentication and they are logged in after authentication then you will have access to the authenticated user with `request.user`.

If not then you can pass the primary key through the urls to the next page and get the user from there: `user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)`